# What is the best way to cut down a hash to a desired size while retaining the quality of the original hash as much as possible?

Tags: c++, c, hash

I have a hash function that takes 64-bit input and outputs 64-bit integer. The hash table's size is `2 ^ 16 = 0x10000`, so I can't use the whole 64-bit hash. I have to cut down to 16-bits, but I want to keep the quality of the original hash as much as possible, so that it's randomly and equally distributed.

With a hash function,

```
uint64_t hash64(uint64_t);
```

I can use the lower bits,

```
uint16_t hash16_low(uint64_t a) {
    return hash64(a) & 0xffff;
}
```

or maybe using higher bits is better,

```
uint16_t hash16_high(uint64_t a) {
    return hash64(a) >> 0x30;
}
```

or I can split the hash and merge with xor. At least no information is lost completely this way,

```
uint16_t hash16_splitXor(uint64_t a) {
    uint16_t b[4];
    memcpy(b, &a, sizeof(uint64_t));
    return *b ^ b[1] ^ b[2] ^ b[3];
}
```

or there is a better way. What is the best way to achieve this?

---

As a reply to a comment by @dratenik, this is the hash function I'm using, which is a specialization of [fast-hash](https://github.com/ztanml/fast-hash/blob/master/fasthash.c) for 64-bit input with a seed of `0x5555555555555555`. I'm not sure about its cryptographic qualities, and it's not meant for such use, but at least it's statistically well-tested. Will it be enough to take either higher or lower bits?

```
static inline uint64_t xorShift64_(uint64_t a, int sh) {
    return a ^ a >> sh;
}

static inline uint64_t hash64_mix_(uint64_t a) {
    return xorShift64_(xorShift64_(a, 23) * 0x2127599bf4325c37u, 47);
}

static inline uint64_t hash64_(uint64_t a) {
    const uint64_t m = 0x880355f21e6d1965u;
    return hash64_mix_((hash64_mix_(a) ^ m * 8 ^ 0x5555555555555555u) * m);
}
```

Comment: If your hash function is cryptographically good - [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) and all that then information should be evenly distributed in the hash. [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) does its 224 and 384 variants by taking bits from the start of the hash (your option #2), but you can use the lower ones instead if you like. The xor thing costs more and should have no real advantage. But hard to say without knowing more about your hash function. There is no generic advice that would apply to all possible functions.

Comment: @dratenik: your comment would make a perfect answer :)

Comment: Three XORs doesn’t exactly cost a lot!

Comment: @dratenik I made an edit with the hash function in use.

Comment: Why calculate a 64 bit hash from a 64 bit value when you actually need a 16 bit hash?

Comment: Looking at the actual hash, although it's not cryptographic it's not a trivial hash and I would expect @dratenik's comment to apply. I would just take the low-order 16-bits. Now you might consider whether hash flooding attacks are an issue, and whether something like siphash is more appropriate.